# angular6 Error in Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: angular6

```
this._weatherService.getWeather(this.location.city,this.location.code).subscribe((response) => {
     console.log(response);
     this.weather = response;
   });
```

> getting this error "message": "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on
>   type 'void'."

Comment: can you show us `getWeather` function

Comment: this is getweather()                                                                                                                   getWeather(city, code) {

     this.http.get(this.url + city + ',' + code + 'AppId=' + this.apiKey).pipe(map((res) => {res.json(); } ) );
  }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issuse is because you did not **return** anything from `getWeather()`

As said in error `void`(means you did not return anything)

**SO in `getWeather()` use `return`:**

```
getWeather(..){
...
return whatever_you_have_to_return;
}
```

Comment: getWeather(city, code) {

     this.http.get(this.url + city + ',' + code + 'AppId=' + this.apiKey).pipe(map((res) => {res.json(); } ) );
  }